# How to hide all subdivision to optimize viewport

Tags: 3d-view, optimization

I'm working on a scene that is entirely based on subdivision loops, As time passes by the scene got detailed and the view-port got laggy.
I turned off subdivision views to optimize it, but that meant I'll have to go through hundreds of assets. Its there a shorter and safer way to turn off all subdivision?

Comment: Try [simplify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/scenes/properties.html#simplify).

Comment: You can set the view subdivision level of a selection of objects simultaneously by hitting Ctrl + keyboard 0 - 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered already in the comment, the global solution is in Render Properties panel, enable simplify sub-menu, and set the max-subdivision level to your preference.
Notice that there are separate inputs for viewport and render.

Answer (score 2):

first select all the meshes with subdivision and select one active object(indicated by yellow)

[image]

then turn of subdivision surface modifier on that mesh.
[image]

after that click on that eye thing and right click

[image]

then just click on copy to selected and you shouold be fine

[image]

Comment: That still meant work. The simplify option did it for me.